# Display youtube video in angular carousel using node.js for url stored in db

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, youtube

I am using the PostgreSQL and I'm storing the youtube url in the database. So according to that url, how to display the video in the angular carousel? For backend i am using node.js.

Comment: Share some code with us and what you have already tried

Comment: I am asking how to do it. So kindly help me